# Angular RC6 - avoid refreshind data in already created view (avoid view flickering)

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a `TodoService` which returns stream of data as `Observable<Todo>`. Inside `TodoService` I read data from a rest API using http.

I need to use this service in 2 components `Page1Component` and `Page2Component`. Thus I inject the service in constructor.

Those 2 components are displayed on separate pages available from application menu using `<router-outlet>`. Each component shows list of todos but in a different matter.

First I used `ngOnInit` but this is called every time a component is shown. It causes flickering of view with `Todo`s. I'd like to have this view solid and changing only when data in stream changes.

The same effect of flickering you can observe in [Tour of heroes demo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html) when you switch between pages `Dashboard` and `Heroes`.

Comment: The Plunker link is broken (empty Plunker).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer link fixed

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are injecting 2 instances of the same service.

If so, probably you need to inject the service in the parent component in order to share it between both components.

ps. a shared variable as cache in memory should be saved in service. Then every component could just load the cache if it is already updated via API.

Comment: I inject the same service to both components.

Comment: It does not depend in which constructor you inject the service. I think it depends on where you provide the service.